# mysql implicit join+ subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, implicit

I'm meant to **use an implicit join** to get all the movies with angelina jolie as director or were she stars here's what I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, relYear
FROM actor,movie 
WHERE director ='Angelina Jolie' OR aID in (SELECT aID 
                                            FROM actor
                                             WHERE fName='Angelina' and surname='Jolie'
```

Here are the relevant tables

```
movie(id, title, relYear, category, runTime, director,
studioName, description, rating)
actor(aID, fName, surname, gender)
stars(movieID, actorID)
movGenre(movieID, genre)
```

This returns all of the movies , I think that's because of `aID in (SELECT aID`

I don't know how to do this without using explicit join on three tables is the subquery even the most efficient approach ? Thanks

Comment: Which college/university teaches still teaches and insist implicit joins ? They should upgrade the coursework and switch to modern approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do on MSSQL. Think it should work on MySql.

```
Select title, relYear FROM movie WHERE director = 'Angelina Jolie' OR id IN 
(SELECT movieId FROM stars inner join actor ON stars.actorId = actor.aID WHERE
 actor.fName = 'Angelina' AND surname = 'Jolie')
```